# Google OAuth2 workflow for mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, native

I'm building a backend for Android/iOS application for the first time. I'm familiar with OAuth2 workflow in web-application environments, but I don't really know what is the recommended approach to take in native application.

Application's back-end will need to use access token generated by Google OAuth2 servers to access user's profile. The question is, is it better to  perform complete token exchange chain on the client side and then send access token and refresh token to application back-end, or is it better to use backend-endpoint to perform the last authorization step (receive access/refresh token) and then somehow send notification to user's device to notify it that authorization is complete. Is there any examples of such functionality that I can take a look at? Ideal approach should be similar between android and ios.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach mentioned by you is good to go with you have to design backend in a way as you did before you dont have to do something extra if android/iOS clients are on front end. Simply last authorization step (receive access/refresh token) and then somehow send notification to user's device to notify it that authorization is complete is good enough. Then You can use several libraries to get token and use it as authorization headers in your future connections of app with backend.